# Can someone join a group of people to travel to a tourist site while fasting?

Tags: ramadan, sawm, travelling

Please do help me to know if someone can join a group of people to travel to a tourist site while fasting?

Answer (score 0):

### All perfect praise be to Allah

Islam encourages to travel and see the creation of Allah and also to see what happened to the people who didn't follow the teachings of their prophet's.

> قُلْ سِيرُوا فِي الْأَرْضِ فَانظُرُوا كَيْفَ بَدَأَ الْخَلْقَ ۚ ثُمَّ
>   اللَّهُ يُنشِئُ النَّشْأَةَ الْآخِرَةَ ۚ إِنَّ اللَّهَ عَلَىٰ كُلِّ
>   شَيْءٍ قَدِيرٌ 
> Say: **"Travel in the land and see how (Allah) originated
>   creation, and then Allah will bring forth (resurrect) the creation of
>   the Hereafter (i.e. resurrection after death). Verily, Allah is Able
>   to do all things."** (Quran 29/20)

and

> قُلْ سِيرُوا فِي الْأَرْضِ فَانظُرُوا كَيْفَ كَانَ عَاقِبَةُ
>   الْمُجْرِمِينَ
>  Say to them (O Muhammad SAW) **"Travel in the land
>   and see how has been the end of the criminals (those who denied
>   Allah's Messengers and disobeyed Allah)."** (Quran 27/69)

**So, you can travel there is no issue, if you think this travelling will lead you to break your fast, than don't do it unnecessarily.**

If anyone forbids you to travel while fasting he must present the proof for his view.

### Allah knows best

Comment: Aren't you contradicting yourself here? You start your sentence saying  there's "no issue" with travelling, then finish your sentence by saying "don't do it".

Comment: @goldPseudo There is ACTUALLY no contradiction, i told what islam says about traveling, it is encouraged. But not on the cost of better things like ramzan fasting and daily prayers etc. Because ramazan fasting and daily prayers are FARZ and most important things, while travelling is encouraged but is not more important that these things. Hope this clears.